# How to check if the document is empty by pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I tried to prevent pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: No operations to execute after getting aggregate function's result. However, the way I used still shows pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: No operations to execute for db.collection.insert(). I believe the result is not null at the beginning case.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client['movies']

for i in range(1,db.movies.count() + 1):
    res = db.ratings.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"movieID":str(i)}}, 
        {"$group": {"_id": "$movieID", "avg": {"$avg":"$rating"}}}
        ])
    if list(res) != None:
        db.question1.insert(res)
```

So how to check the document is empty in MongoDB?

Comment: why store empty documents ? this raised a lot `_id` error. Create an clean-up script ! You can't fix an ON-CREATE error on ON-USE step !

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that may be wrong here: one is that a lot of pymongo's functions return iterators. For example:

```
query = db.customers.find({ 'name': 'John' })
# will print the number of Johns
print len(list(query))
# will always print 0, because the query results have already been
# consumed
print len(list(query))
```

Python's `list` function takes an iterator and creates a list with all the elements returned by the iterator, so `list(query)` will create a list with everything returned by the query. But, if we don't store the result of `list(query)` in a variable, they are lost forever and can't be accessed again ;-)

I'm not sure whether this is the case for `aggregate` or not. If it is, the moment you called `list(res)` you basically consumed all the results, so you can't access them a second time when you call `insert(res)` because they are already gone.

The other issue is that `list(res)` is never `None`. If there are no results, `list(res)` will be `[]` so you actually want to check simply `if list(res)` or `if len(list(res)) > 0`. Putting these two suggestions together, we get:

```
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client['movies']

for i in range(1,db.movies.count() + 1):
    # Convert db.ratings.aggregate directly to a list
    # Now `res` is a simple list, which can be accessed
    # and traversed many times
    res = list(db.ratings.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"movieID":str(i)}}, 
        {"$group": {"_id": "$movieID", "avg": {"$avg":"$rating"}}}
        ]))
    if len(res) > 0:
        db.question1.insert(res)
```